# Cannot access video file in MEDIA folder

Tags: python, django

Here's a weird one. I'm building a basic app that let's users upload videos and then play them back. Simple. When the user uploads a file, a link to it is stored in mysql, and the file itself is stored on the filesystem in web_app/media/videos/.

In settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web_app/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My relevant directory structure:

```
project/web_app/static/
project/web_app/media/
```

The upload works fine, and then both the db entry and the video file land as expected. The problem is that I can't access the file via a video link. Right now, in my view template, I have this:

```
{% block body %}
    <div><video src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ path_to_video }}" width=640 height=360 controls></video></div>
    <div><video src="/static/videos/2015/05/18/vid1.mp4" width=640 height=360 controls></video></div>
{% endblock body %}
```

The first div is obviously what I'm trying to use, and the second is there for debugging - you'll see why in a second. This template results in the following html:

```
<div><video src="/media/videos/2015/05/18/vid1.mp4" width=640 height=360 controls></video></div>
<div><video src="/static/videos/2015/05/18/vid1.mp4" width=640 height=360 controls></video></div>
```

Again, as expected. Here's the thing: the first link doesn't work, saying it can't find the file. But if I manually copy 'videos/2015/etc..." into the /static folder, then the second link works as expected. What's going on here? Is there some permission issue with the media folder?

I don't know if it makes a difference but this is on Windows...  Thanks.

Comment: Are you just using dev server or are you using apache/nginx in front?

Comment: dev server via pycharm.

Comment: can change the permissions (temporarily) to 777 or the windows equivalent just to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that someone experiences with the Django **development server**. This is what I have in my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # pragma: nocover
```

On **live/production** this should be handled by the web server.

(The `#pragma` comment is for the `coverage` package.)

The above is covered in the [Django documentation: Serving files uploaded by a user during **development**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development). See also [Serving static files during **development**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

Comment: It works! I don't understand it, though. What is this entry doing?

Comment: I am very glad it did. I have provided links to the documentation. Not too much detail though. The Django development server does not serve these files.

Comment: Needs a big disclaimer: this is for **development only**.